# Import images from object array in map with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
export const NGOarray = [
  {
    name: "1% for the Planet ",
    description:
      "A leading global nonprofit, building a movement of businesses and individuals delivering philanthropic support to environmental organizations working on the front lines for our planet.",
    link: "https://onepercentfortheplanet.org/",
    category: ["water", "everything"],
    logo: "1fortheplanet.webp",
  },
  {
    name: "4ocean",
    description:
      "As both a public benefit corporation and Certified B Corp, we’re committed to ending the ocean plastic crisis.",
    link: "https://www.4ocean.com",
    category: ["water", "everything"],
    logo: "4 Ocean.svg",
  } ]
```

The logo property maps to the filename they have in a folder.
I'm trying to map through that array and show each image like this:

```
{NGOarray.map((org) => {
        
                <div key={org.name}>
                  {org.logo && (
                    <img
                         src={
                    require(`../assets/organizations/${org.logo}`)
                      .default
                  }
                    />
                  )}
                  <h3 className="text-2xl font-sans mb-4">{org.name}</h3>
                  <p>{org.description}</p>
                </div>
              );
            }
```

But the image won't show up.
Any idea how I can get it to work?

Comment: try to include images as `require("../assets/organizations/4 Ocean.svg")
                      .default` in the NGOarray array for every object in the array

Comment: @ManishSencha as in  {
    name: "1% for the Planet ",
    description:
      "...",
    link: "https://onepercentfortheplanet.org/",
    category: ["water", "everything"],
    logo: "require('../assets/organizations/1fortheplanet.webp').default",
  } ?

Comment: logo: require('../assets/organizations/1fortheplanet.webp').default
and 
src={org.logo}

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this seems to have worked, leaving answer here for reference:

```
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const logos = importAll(
  require.context("../assets/organizations/", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
);
```

And when mapping the array:

```
{NGOarray.map((org, index) => {
                <div key={org.name}>
                  {org.logo && <img src={logos[index]} alt={org.name} />}
                  <h3 className="text-2xl font-sans mb-4">{org.name}</h3>
                  <p>{org.description}</p>
                </div>
              );
            }
```